# Proving that the complexity class $P$ is closed under union

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, polynomial-time

The following is my proof for $P$ being closed under union. I wish to know if my proof is correct in addition to what it means for the union of two problems.

Proof:

Let $p_1, p_2 \in P$ Then by definition of $P$ $p_1$ is solvable in $O(n^k)$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Similarly $p_2$ is solvable in $O(n^{k_2}$) for some $k_2\in\mathbb{N}$.

Then to solve $p_1 \cup p_2$, we solve $p_1$ and $p_2$. So the total running time would be $O(n^k) + O(n^{k_2}) = O(n^{\max(k, k_2)})$

1. What does it mean to solve $p_1 \cup p_2$?
2. Is my proof correct or on the right track?

Comment: I'm not sure what the proof has to do with the question, do you mean to ask what the union of two problems is (which is what the question you have asks), or are you trying to get people to check your proof (which is discouraged on this site).

Answer (score 2):

Thinking about the problems as languages is probably the most illuminating way here. A language is a just a subset of all possible strings (over some alphabet $\Sigma$ which might as well be $\{0,1\}$). A language $\Pi \subseteq \Sigma^{\ast}$ is in $\mathsf{P}$ if there exists an algorithm that given a string $x \in \Sigma^{\ast}$ decides whether $x \in \Pi$ or $x \notin \Pi$ in time bounded by $\mathcal{O}(|x|^{c})$ for some constant $c$.

Relating that to the "problem" style definition, $x$ is the input (or rather the string that encodes the input) and $x \in \Pi$ is the same as saying $x$ is a Yes-instance of $\Pi$.

Taking the language definition though makes it easy to talk about the union, intersection etc., as languages/problems are just sets. So a string/instance being a member of the union of two languages/Yes-instance of the union of two problems, is exactly what it says on the tin: if the two problems are $p_{1}$ and $p_{2}$, then $x \in p_{1}$ and $x \in p_{2}$, or equivalently $x$ is a Yes-instance of $p_{1}$ and $x$ is a Yes-instance of $p_{2}$.